# Will managed files be deleted if no corresponding entry exists in file_usage?

Tags: 7, files

I am using the services module to implement a REST API.  One resource allows POSTs with uploaded files.  During a services pre-process function I save the file to the temp directory.  During a services post-process function, I move the file to a private directory, call file_usage_add, and save the host entity.  When a validation error occurs between saving the temp file and moving the temp file to a permanent location, I am not explicitly deleting the temp file.  I thought drupal cron would take care of this for me, since no entry for this file exists in file_usage.  However, it doesn't appear that cron is taking care of this for me.  Any thoughts as to why this is?

When reviewing file_managed, I see the temporary file that I'd like deleted.  When reviewing file_usage, I don't see any corresponding record.

Update -- One additional piece of info: in most cases, the file is actually missing.  I believe this is due to OS reboot clearing out the /tmp directory.  Regardless, would system_cron still remove the file_managed entry for a file if the actual file were no longer found?

This problem arose since I started uploading files from a native mobile app. The filename is the same every upload.  There are some cases where the temp filename doesn't exist in the /tmp directory, but a record in file_managed still exists with a URI of that filename.  So I'm getting an integrity error when the file_managed table is being saved.  I plan on updating the app to create a random filename.  In the meantime, I'd like to clean up the database and surrounding "glue" logic that manages these files.  If system_cron will do it all for me then great.  But from what I can tell, system_cron is not removing old, completely unused (and unreferenced) records in file_managed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Drupal automatically deletes temporary files in [system_cron()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.module/function/system_cron/7).

Permament files which have no file_usage are not deleted, however.

Comment: That's what I thought.  However, entries in file_managed are still hanging around, even though no corresponding entries exist in file_usage, and no actual file exists anymore.  I must be missing something here...

Comment: @lkiss80 The file won't be deleted unless it has a `status` of zero in the `file_managed` table

Comment: And additionally, must be older than 6 hours.

Comment: @Clive - Thanks. Your response prompted me to double checked the status bit. I originally referenced a book that incorrectly flipped the meaning of this bit.  Thanks again!