# Uploaded image is not being deleted after refresh

Tags: media, files

I have a content type with a field type image. When I create a new node of that content type and click the browse button and then upload the image and immediately I refresh the page, every field is empty (that is ok), but the file remains in the files folder even after I run cron.

I checked the database and the file is set in the table file_managed with the status 0. Is weird because after the cron the uploaded image should be removed.

Any clue? Thanks!

Comment: Drupal will delete this file during `cron`. Dont worry keep rocking with Drupal.

Comment: That is the problem, I ran the cron several times but the file is still in the files folder.

Comment: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/27311/4471 Permament files which have no file_usage are not deleted, however.

Comment: The cron takes care of the temporary files older than DRUPAL_MAXIMUM_TEMP_FILE_AGE (6 hours). Thanks both of you guys!